# Height of the Image placed inside div container - CSS

Tags: css, image, height

unfortunately I have problem with setting image height with CSS, I've searched many places but found no answer that helped. Let me explain the problem. I have following CSS (it works) :

```
#cube
{
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 80%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    text-align : center;
}

#cube
{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media screen  {
    #cube {
        max-height: 80%;
        max-width: 80%;
    }
}        

</style>
```

for the image :

```
<img src="res/cube_na_strone.png" class="ri" id="cube"/><br />
```

It's working fine - but there is no container. When I added container in order to position text... :

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
    font-family : Arial;
}

#cubeContainer
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;     
    text-align : center;  
}

#cubeContainer
{
    top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-90%, -60%);
}

#cube, #google {
    position : relative;
    top : 0px;
    left : 0px;       
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;    
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

#cube:hover, #google:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}


#googleContainer
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 60%;
    text-align : center;  
}

#googleContainer
{
    top: 50%;
    left: 60%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-10%, -60%);
}

#cube, #google {
    position : relative;
    top : 0px;
    left : 0px;       
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom : 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

#cube:hover, #google:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

@media screen  {
    #cubeContainer , #googleContainer {
        max-height: 80%;
        max-width: 40%;
    }
}
```

For following elements :

```
<body>
    <div id="cubeContainer">
        <img src="res/cube_na_strone.png" class="ri" id="cube"/><br />
        <a id="cube_a"  href="#">Wirtualne wycieczki</a>
    </div>


    <div id="googleContainer">
        <img src="res/googleview.png" class="ri"  id="google"/><br />
        <a id="A1"  href="#">Business View w mapach Google</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Problem begins :( Image's height remains unchanged.

Here are those sites :

http://vr.fotomilo.pl/

http://vr.fotomilo.pl/vr.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Containers #cubeContainer and #googleContainer need height. Try to set height to 100%

Comment: Yes Yes! That works! I thought that rule :
            @media screen  {
          #cubeContainer , #googleContainer {
              max-height: 80%;
              max-width: 40%;
          }
        }

will set containers height, in IE when I pressed F12 and checked elements properties - containers appeared to be ok. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

try changing the image's dimensions via this rule:

```
div#cubeContainer img{}
div#googleContainer img{}
```